# Django - Redirect at login based on group

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-authentication

I am currently working on a Django project that has a number of user groups. After login, I am looking to redirect each user to a unique page created for that group.

I have already created the login functionality but for the life of me cannot figure out how to redirect based on group. If there is more efficient way of doing this, I am also open to other suggestions.

The reason for having a separate page for each group is due to a wide range of permissions. I don't want to show a user an option that they would be unable to access.

Thanks in advance.

----Edit----

To expand on the above statement, I have extended the user model to include some needed parameters and set AUTH_USER_MODEL to 'User_Profile.User' (the application created for the extended user model) in settings.py.

In views.py, I am attempting to redirect based on user group based on the below code; however, when redirecting I receive an AttributeError stating that "type object User has no attribute 'groups'. In an html template I am able to access {{user.groups.all.0}} correctly.

From views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from User_Profile.models import User

@login_required
    def home(request):
if User.groups.filter(name='group1') == True:
    return render_to_response("home.html", locals(),
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    return render_to_response("login.html", locals(),
              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: could you post some code please?

Comment: See new edits above. Will add more code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered, rather than having many separate different templates, you could have one template, and in django's template language you can do

```
{% if user.permission %}
    <!-- whatever needs to be put here based on the user's permission -->
{% endif %}
```